# Can a constrained question be closed with a general target, if part of an answer on the target answers the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

This question [What is the regex form of '' in the split function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65388062) was asked about 2 months ago, and was closed as "Needs details or clarity", then deleted, then undeleted, and finally reopened.

A few hours ago, it was suggested that the question is a duplicate of [How to get character array from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609). This was disputed in the comments, with the claim that the questions are different. The user who suggested the duplicate pointed out that one part of one of one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717402) could actually be used as an answer to the original question, and hence the duplicate closure was justified.

The user then posted a `cv-pls` request in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org) for the original question, where I noticed it and raised the [same objection](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51590528), and received essentially the same [response](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51590546):

> ... Both questions ask the same thing, one adds an extra constraint, and the other happens to cover that as well.

This duplicate closure seems odd to me. To my understanding, the questions themselves need to be the same to be considered duplicates, which doesn't appear to be the case here. Of course, if the answers on the target could be used to answer the original question, that certainly suggests that they are duplicates. As the close banner says:

> This question already has answers here:

This suggests to me that I should be able to take the answer from the target, and use it as an answer for the original. This doesn't seem to be the case here, since over 80% of that answer is completely irrelevant to the original question.

By the metric of "This question already has answers here:", I could see an argument for *reversing* the direction of the duplicate targets, but that would give only very incomplete answers on the current target.

I don't think any reasonable answer to one of these questions could be used to properly answer the other, and as such, I don't think the duplicate closure is valid.

So my question is, is this a valid duplicate closure? This considerably broadens the scope of what I understand to be valid as duplicate closures, and I'm looking for feedback from the community on whether this is acceptable and/or a good idea.

Note that whether the original question is off-topic or not, for any reason, is completely irrelevant to my question. It's also irrelevant if there is some *other* target that happens to be an exact duplicate of the original question.

Comment: Only one answer addresses the problem or the question itself is a generic form of the problem? Like "2+2?" closed against "how to add numbers?".

Comment: @Braiam In my opinion, the former, and specifically, just one part of one answer. I've linked both the questions, so you can take a look at them yourself. I might be wrong of course, and would appreciate any feedback about that.

Comment: What is the downside of the duplicate closure, as long as there is a suitable solution somewhere at the end of it?

Comment: IMO, yes, it's a perfectly valid closure, OP gets the answer that they're looking for, as well as other answers which may be helpful. *"specifically asking for alternative of split('') should not be exact dupe of that question"* is not a valid argument, it's not like the question disappears or is no longer accessible, the question in its current form is and will remain available, it simply has a pointer to another question as well. This is even expressed in the dupe banner: *"This question already has answers here: "*, notably _not_ *"This question is the same as: "*.

Comment: @khelwood I didn't say there was any downside. In fact, if this is an acceptable closure, I wouldn't mind at all. Especially since I have a hammer, this would let me close many more questions than I can currently. I'm just not sure this is acceptable and that's what I'm asking feedback on. I've tried not to state my preference either way in the question.

Comment: Then read my comment as "What argument is there that this should not be acceptable"?

Comment: @Nick and khelwood: Well, kind of. There's part of an answer on the duplicate target that has a solution to the original question. The OP could reasonably work out the answer to their question from that. But that's true of any RTFM target, and those are definitely not acceptable. This closure seems to come close to that, and I'm trying to figure out where to draw the line.

Comment: related at MSE: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217401/165773)

Comment: @khelwood if the answer didn't exist in the target, would they be considered still duplicates?

Comment: @oguzismail So, the fact that there is an Answer, where a subset of it just happens to be a solution, is enough? That doesn't seem right to me. In my opinion, only if any Answer that answers another Question is also an Answer to this one, then it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, except *a subset of it* part doesn't sound right to me. In this case the goal is the same in both the duplicate and the original, *a subset of it happens to be a solution* doesn't reflect that well. If you said *the fact that there is an answer, which answers both questions* instead (which is the case here), then I could say *yes, absolutely* with contentment.

Comment: @gnat Your suggested duplicate doesn't seem to be remotely related; perhaps you picked up on the "RTFM" keyword I used in a comment. The MSE post that you linked is definitely very related though.

Comment: @oguzismail Actually, there doesn't seem to be any answer on the target that answers both questions. A *part* of the answer that you pointed to could be used, but that seems to be a bit of a stretch as far as closing as duplicate goes. I've edited my question to clarify that a bit.

Comment: @khelwood To expand upon Braiam's comment, if the answer didn't contain the regex solutions, would they still be considered duplicates? Note that the answer would be completely correct for the target question without those regex solutions.

Comment: The answer I pointed to answers the duplicate very well @cigien, the solution it provides covers edge cases too, unlike the answers on the duplicate. Why do you think it's a *stretch*?

Comment: @ciglen In that circumstance it would be unhelpful to close it as a duplicate (until a suitable answer had been added), because "your question has an answer here" would not be true.

Comment: @oguzismail A *part* of the answer on the target answers the original, that's true. From what I've seen, that's not really a metric that qualifies a question as a duplicate. At least in the C++ tag, where I hammer questions relatively actively, this closure would not fly (if noticed, of course). A *very* large number of questions would *happen* to have solutions embedded in answers somewhere on SO, and I wasn't aware that they could be used as duplicate targets.

Comment: @khelwood Ok, that makes more sense. I would still say: "your question already has answers here" is not exactly right in this case.

Comment: If you provide a conrete example to that we can discuss it, otherwise I don't see any point in arguing over this one because you don't want to understand that there is an authoritative answer that answers the duplicate, and that it is a good thing that we refer future visitors there because the duplicate has two partial answers that work on sunny Wednesdays only if you're lucky.

Comment: @oguzismail the main point is: if that answer didn't exist, would the question still be a duplicate? Why?

Comment: @Braiam Again, no. But it **does** exist, and not likely to disappear any time soon.

Comment: @oguzismail that's not how duplicate questions are supposed to work. They are duplicate _questions_, it's ridiculous that we couldn't say that two questions aren't duplicate just because they happen to have the only two answers in different questions. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is it reasonable to close "How do I do X using regex?" as a duplicate of "How do I do X?" if the latter has answers that use regex? To me it seems completely reasonable. I am not a JavaScript expert, so there might be some nuance to these particular questions that I am missing.

Comment: @Braiam I have no idea what you're talking about. If you actually have an argument that invalidates the closure in question, please rephrase it because I don't understand that comment.

Comment: The very intent of 2 questions are different. Seeing comment from OP, he is well aware of the other question and all existing answers. IMO, just having a similar *partial* answer on a different question doesn't make it dupe. Using this yardstick, hundreds of new questions can be marked dupe.

Comment: @anubhava As far as I can tell, you haven't voted to reopen this Meta question. Doing that would be helpful to get answers that can expand upon these arguments in detail, since the comments seem to be going around in circles. (And the current target for this Meta is quite inappropriate anyway).

Comment: Voted to reopen this question

Comment: @anubhava 1. What do you mean the *intent*? 2. How does any of that make the duplicate *not* a duplicate? Practically, the question you answered asks *how to explode a string in javascript?* as well, the only difference is its author is seeking a solution that uses regular expressions. And such a solution is already provided in the duplicate target. If the question you answered asked *what is the regular expression to match the empty string between characters in a string?* instead, then it'd be a different question. But that is not the case here.

Comment: OP's verbatim words "this one definitely answers my question but the intention is not perfect. The question that he answered is entirely different from what I have asked." So clearly OP thinks otherwise

Comment: What OP thinks is completely irrelevant, and in this case wrong too. We do not ask OP before closing a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Everyone's understanding can be different. On this one I completely agree with OP.

Comment: @oguzismail don't use answers to evaluate duplicate questions! It only leads to ridiculous situations like what you recognized that would happen if the answer wasn't there.

Comment: The answer is there, @Braiam.

Comment: @oguzismail again, that's ridiculous, it isn't scalable and not how the system is meant to be used!

Comment: Do! exclamation! marks! make! nonsensical! comments! more! agreeable?! Seriously though, post an answer and explain why exactly it is wrong and ridiculous and how the system is meant to be used.

Comment: @oguzismail I do not have to do that. You should explain it yourself because what you say do not make any sense! Instead of arguing with me, explain how something so illogical makes sense, because your terse comments do nothing of the sort. It's basically a circular argument.

Comment: @khelwood no, it's not reasonable, because if the answers weren't there you wouldn't close them. It is a departure of what duplicates mean traditionally: this question was asked before. If you can't post all answers of the target on the supposed duplicate, saying that they are the same question is very suspect at best, counterproductive at worst.

Comment: @Braiam You seem very convinced, but beyond it not being how you think duplicates are supposed to work, I don't understand your objection.

Comment: I have already explained it above, more than once. I conclude that all you have against the closure in question is a silly argument entirely based on *that is ridiculous* that goes literally nowhere, and exclamation points here and there. Have a nice day @Braiam

Comment: @khelwood Duplicates are supposed to be the same question asked twice, maybe using different words, but _the same question_. Look for Dr. Strangedupe for how the system was supposed to work. Whatever you think it does work, it's an aberration apart of having no logical explanation of why it should be that way.

Comment: @oguzismail no, I'm against absurd duplicate closure. I would close more questions as duplicate if they were not at the bottom of my peeking order. Other close reasons are more important to me to act on, that doesn't mean that I would call something ridiculous when it is.